# On button click, is there any possibility of create an image with backend response data and created image need to download

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have button, when I click on button , Iam getting the encrypted  string response from backend, with this response I need to create a image and then download the created image.

Could you please any one  help on this requirement?

Comment: I donot have any code as of now. I need to implement code by reference.

Comment: encrypted means in base 64 format??

Comment: First you need to bind the data using ngsrc.Look in official documentation.eg. <img ng-src="{{mainImageUrl}}" class="phone">

Comment: implement that much post the code and then we will think of downloading the image